# Neural Network(Multilayer Perceptron) config to approximate the sine function

Tags: neural-network

I write a multilayer perceptron and try to approximate the sine function.

My network contains only a single hidden layer with 50 neurals (input layer and output layer each has only 1 neural of course). Activation function used in hidden layer is tanh, and output layer is linear. Learning rate is set to 0.0001, momentum 0.9 (normal momentum not Nesterov momentum) Training mode is online since the data is generate without noise. Weights and bias are generate randomly with mean = 0;

After 10000 epochs, my network result plotted below (the upper image is real sine function, the lower image is my network output), although it is not too bad, I cannot achieve the exact sine function.

Can anyone give me advice for a better config for better error convergence.

[image: Top: real sine function; Bottom : network approximation function]